# How to run Jsp files individually

Tags: jsp

I want to be able to run JSP files on the server precisely Plesk Onyx server without having to compress it into a .war archive. Any help or insight is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Right click on the specific jsp file and click run as run on server .

Comment: It doesn't work have tried it before